# Oracle equivalent of useServerPrepStmts=false & rewriteBatchedStatements=true

Tags: mysql, oracle, spring-batch, jdbctemplate

I am batch inserting around 400-500k records in DB using Spring batch and jdbc template batchUpdate().
in order to improve performance in MySQL, I am using 2 parameters ie useServerPrepStmts and rewriteBatchedStatements, final url is

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useSSL=false&useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

which inserts  400-500k records just in couple of seconds

but when I am using the same parameters in ORACLE for same 400-500k records its taking around 35-36 secounds,

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:3855/test?useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

with or without these parameters no effect in performance at all.

what is the correct equivalent variable in ORACLE?

Comment: Where in the [Oracle JDBC manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdbc/index.html) did you find that option?

Comment: not exactly in the ORACLE manual, I found them for MYSQL and was wondering if it's applicable for ORACLE as well. I googled but all available examples were of MYSQL only, I guess there must be some other variables for ORACLE.

Comment: Oracle and MySQL and two very different database systems (although they are both owned by the Oracle corporation). You can not assume that something that works for one also works for the other. You have to consult the manual of each product